# JQuery datables draw next row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

JQuery datables draws the rows by 'page' (numerical increment). Can I then just draw the next row onto the end of that 'page', based on a certain condition? Also the reverse, prefix the previous row based on condition?

My initial thought was using the fnRowCallback, but I doubt that is the best way...

```
"fnRowCallback":function(nRow,nData,iDisplayIndex){
         if(nData[3]=='D"){
             //how to I add the next row 
             //based on if this is the last row on the 'page' and meets certain criteria
         }
 }
```

Extra Situation Info:

The client requested format of table in such a way that the number of rows needed to be seen is not always consistent from a 'per page' of results  (although he still wants to be able to 'page' through them). 
There are times when a certain row may get cut off in a pagination situation, but it needs to be seen in context of the previous 5 rows (the number 5 is not constant either). Yes, it is complicated, yes the pagination is then going to get a little wonky, but it's for his own private administration of a portal and he wants it that way.

Comment: It sounds to me that you need a filter, like a select box, to separate rows with certain values, or simply just need to sort the table according to those values.